# rails 3.1 key value problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

rails 3.1 with ruby 1.9.2p290 on windows generates

**initialers/config/session_store.rb**

```
Hello::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_hello_session'
```

`key: 'hello_session'` is `:key => 'hello_session'` in some of my old apps. What makes rails to generate different codes? Ruby version or rails version ?

Comment: It's Ruby 1.9.2, Ruby 1.8.7 needs :key=> value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a new hash syntax in ruby 1.9, you can write:

```
{key: "hello_session"}
```

instead of:

```
{:key => "hello_session"}
```

The 1.8 syntax is still supported, use it if you want your app to be compatible with both 1.8 and 1.9.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by removing my ~/.rvm directory and reinstalling RVM.